# Perl replace digits in document with math

Tags: perl

I have .csv file in which I'm trying replace all instances of specific value for e.g. height:

```
"_height","10"
"_height","100"
```

I need to divide value by 2.54 and round result to nearest whole number. So far managed to write this one liner, just not sure how to do rounding.

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's|((?<="_height",").[0-9.]+)|($1)/2.54|eg' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sprintf "%0.f", $num` to round

```
 perl -pe's{"_height","\K(\d+)}{sprintf "%0.f", $1/2.54}eg' input.csv
```

This uses [`\K` form](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) of the lookbehind.

If there is any more than this to process I'd recommend to parse the CSV file properly with a module. A good choice is [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm), best with the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.31/CSV_XS.pm) backend.